# tortoise svn - svn:ignore - recursive?

Tags: tortoisesvn

For my job i'm working with starteam.

But I want to try using svn.  So in a first time I installed tortoisesvn on my pc (windows 7 home premium x64)

I have that directory :

```
c:\svn\lab
```

On that directory I do :

```
right click - tortoiseSVN - create a repository here
```

Then I have

```
c:\java\lab
```

and I do

```
right click - SVN checkout - and choose my local repository file:///c:/svn/lab
```

In c:\java\lab, I create that structure

```
│   a.txt
│   b.xlsx
│
├───target
└───test
    │   c.txt
    │   d.xlsx
    │
    └───target
```

and I want to ignore txt files and target directories.

If I do

```
right click - svn commit
```

in the commit dialog all files and directories are in the list -- ok it's normal.

Now I tried

```
svn propset -R svn:ignore *.txt .
```

in the commit dialog, a.txt is not there (cool it's working) but c.txt is still there !!

Idem with target directories.

How can I do ?

Comment: FYI: [Setting svn:ignore property on files that are not version controlled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140802/setting-svnignore-property-on-files-that-are-not-version-controlled) is your case

Comment: Thnanks but ... not working for me.  Don't understand.  I tried svn add --depth=empty c:\java\lab and it gives me c:\java is not a working copy

Answer (score 2):

Right Click on top Directory > TortoiseSVN > Properties.

In the properties window, check if directory contains `svn:ignore` property. If doesn't, Click 'Add', then set property name `svn:ignore` and property values:

```
*.txt
target.
```

Otherwise, double-click the property.

Check 'Apply Property Recursively'. Click 'Ok'.